# Is it possible to create variables for each instantiation of an object? (as c++)

Tags: tikz-pgf, variable

Let'say I have defined a new command that draws a tikzpicture. Every time I call this command, I 'instantiate' a new 'object'. Is it possible to create variables for each separate object that holds information for this particular object (as c++)?

An example would be a counter that keeps track how many times a certain command has been called. Another example would be this:
[image]

Each box is an instantiated object and each object holds a variable that says to which box it is connected to. How can I access variables of a certain instantiated object?

Comment: TikZ already does ref count what do you want to do with that count?

Comment: I mean not per se refcounts, but variables in general. For example to keep track how many times a certain command has been called

Comment: `\advance\mycounter by 1\relax` inside your command?

Comment: Is it also possible to access a variable belonging to a particular instantiated object?

Comment: Not if you have saved them globally no.  Once the box is shipped out they are forgotten.

Comment: I will try to look at it later but in the mean time you can check TikZ OOP possibilities in the manual.

Comment: I think there's a paradigm mix here. `:)` You don't instantiate, you expand a definition.  In those definitions, there might be hooks in which you can differentiate elements from one expansion to another... Then @percusse brings black belt in TikZ-fu to the arena. `:)`

Comment: Do you mean something as simple as `\newcounter{foocnt}\newcommand{\foo}\stepcounter{foocnt}<some TikZ>}`?

Comment: @PauloCereda I think you can help by going with Section 93 of the manual.

Comment: @percusse: interesting!

Comment: As @percusse said, take a look in Section 93. The manual shows a simple yet useful example on how to create a class and populate it with attributes and methods, and then later create objects like a typical OO environment. Observe that attributes are always marked as `private`, so you'd need to use the module's getter/setter pair to handle them and/or encapsulate their calls in other commands... **Edit:** if you are already familiar with OO from C++, I think you won't have any problems on grasping the example portrayed in the manual. `:)`

Comment: Is it possible you guys can give an example in coding using my drawing as a reference? A small start is enough so I can continue from there on

Comment: anyone please? :)